# Which is best for remote chef-client - knife ssh or regular ssh?

Tags: ssh, chef-infra, knife

Which is best to use for running chef-client remotely? The provided knife ssh command or regular ssh to machine and execute chef-client manually by switching to root. I understand knife ssh talks directly to chef and should be used but is it only recommended to use knife ssh over regular ssh? Are there any drawbacks of using ssh over knife ssh?

Answer (score 1):

What's "best" is subjective and depends on your requirements. Hope you have looked at the [knife ssh](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_ssh/) documentation.

In my opinion, `knife ssh` is good for running commands remotely especially on multiple nodes at the same time. One of the *strong* points of `knife ssh` is that you can target your nodes with a `SEARCH_QUERY`. This allows you to run command on all nodes, single node, or anything in between.

Example: run chef-client on single node `dc-web-srv01.exampleco.net`:

```
knife ssh 'name:dc-web-srv01.exampleco.net' 'sudo chef-client'
```

Example: run chef-client on all web servers matching `dc-web-*`:

```
knife ssh 'name:dc-web-*' 'sudo chef-client'
```

Or if you associate roles with a group of servers like `db-servers`:

```
knife ssh "role:db-servers" "sudo chef-client"
```

You can run any other command as well, if you want to see the `date` on all servers:

```
knife ssh "name:*" "date"
```

Comment: We have no problem using any one. We use roles and we run chef-client over multiple nodes at once. Would you say we should be better with knife ssh as ssh involves complications of sending the commands for chef execution?

Comment: Yes, I think for "bulk" actions where multiple targets need to be reached in parallel `knife ssh` makes sense. Also Chef server ties the infrastructure in a central location as managed nodes, so it makes sense to utilize this centralized control on infrastructure.

Comment: i won't advise you to execute chef-client on a remote over ssh command. when ssh connection is dropped, all sub-processes are killed, which might kill the chef-client run. if you run chef-client periodically, you might consider using a periodic task (cron) or executing chef-client in terminal multiplexer (tmux\screen)